# How to initialize data sturcture before starting spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a some data structure for initializing it I need to make a request to a Database and then invoke object that will prepare data for data structure and only then initialize it. How can I do it  before start spring-mvc application?

I'm trying to use annotation such as @PostConstruct and @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) but they are startup with spring application and at this moment data structure not initialized.

There is code example:

```
public class DataStructure{
    Collection data = new Collection();//some kind of collection



    @PostConstruct
    public void initDS(){
        DataFromDataBase data = ...;
        SomeObjectThatPrepareData obj = new SomeObjectThatPrepareData(data);

        Collection preparedData = obj.prepareData();

        preparedData.forEach(DataStructure::addData);


    }

    private void addData(Data data){ ... }

    ...
}

public class ClassThatUseDataStucture{
     private static DataStructure readyData;
     static{
         readyData = new DataStructure();
         readyData.initDS();
     }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to setup/initialize something at Spring boot application startup, you should use either `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner`.

Spring boot provides an `ApplicationRunner` interface with a callback run() method which can be invoked at application startup after the Spring application context is instantiated.

e.g.

```
@Component
public class AppStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        // Setup or initialization activities
    }
}
```

Or You can create Bean as suggested by Aniket in the comments:

```
@Bean 
ApplicationRunner thisWillRunAutomatically() 
{
    return args -> { ... };
}
```

Read more about Spring boot callbacks here: [Spring boot callbacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html)

Comment: Better setup a `@Bean ApplicationRunner thisWillRunAutomatically() {return args -> ...}`